# ggplot seems to plot the date object differently

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have the data as follows. I am trying to plot the discrete data on top of time series.

```
df1 <- structure(list(sample_date = structure(c(1418233320, 1418233320, 
1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 
1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 1418233320, 
1418233320, 1418233320), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), start_depth = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 
9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5), chemical_name = c("Salinity (field)", 
"Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", 
"Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", 
"Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", 
"Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)", "Salinity (field)"), 
    result_value = c(2.25, 2.16, 2.26, 3.41, 14.96, 19.17, 21.66, 
    22.18, 22.96, 23.16, 23.32, 23.54, 23.6, 23.66, 23.67, 23.67
    )), .Names = c("sample_date", "start_depth", "chemical_name", 
"result_value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L
))

df2 <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1418198455, 1418199355, 
1418200255, 1418201155, 1418202054, 1418202955, 1418203854, 1418204754, 
1418205655, 1418206555, 1418207454, 1418208354, 1418209255, 1418210155, 
1418211054, 1418211954, 1418212854, 1418213754, 1418214654, 1418215554, 
1418216455, 1418217355, 1418218254, 1418219154, 1418220054, 1418220954, 
1418221854, 1418222754, 1418223655, 1418224554, 1418225455, 1418226355, 
1418227255, 1418228155, 1418229054, 1418229954, 1418230854), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Depth = c(1.15, 1.23, 1.29, 1.32, 1.33, 1.39, 1.47, 
1.5, 1.49, 1.54, 1.6, 1.61, 1.67, 1.76, 1.78, 1.71, 1.68, 1.74, 
1.76, 1.62, 1.46, 1.41, 1.39, 1.32, 1.24, 1.18, 1.13, 1.07, 0.99, 
0.91, 0.86, 0.83, 0.75, 0.66, 0.58, 0.5, 0.44), Sal1 = c(5.97000000000001, 
9.61000000000001, 12.08, 12.81, 12.31, 12.74, 14.27, 13.42, 9.09000000000001, 
13.24, 12.11, 13.58, 12.89, 13.85, 14.56, 14.06, 13.56, 13.27, 
13.69, 14.81, 14.02, 12.49, 11.79, 12.31, 11.88, 10.7, 11.5, 
10.2, 9.77000000000001, 7.43000000000001, 6.81000000000001, 5.94000000000001, 
5.36000000000001, 3.75000000000001, 1.78000000000001, 1.36000000000001, 
1.27000000000001)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -37L
), .Names = c("datetime", "Depth", "Sal1"))
```

Plot the data

```
ggplot(df2) + geom_line(aes(datetime, Sal1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(as.POSIXct(sample_date), as.numeric(result_value)), data = df1)
```

Also used the following code but the output looks similar:

```
ggplot(df2) + geom_line(aes(datetime, Sal1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(sample_date, result_value), data = df1)
```

Output looks like:

[image]

The points don't seem to line up properly.

However, when plotted on excel the data seem to line up correctly. It is as follows:

[image]

**Based on joran's comment**
I changed the attributes of POSIXct objects and made them both GMT but still not lining up. Did I do something wrong ?

```
attr(df2$datetime, "tzone") <- "GMT"
attr(df1$sample_date, "tzone") <- "GMT"

ggplot(df2) + geom_line(aes(datetime, Sal1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(sample_date, result_value), data = df1)
```

Comment: The two POSIXct columns have different time zones.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize they had different time zones. But I changed the attribute and tried to run the code. Still got same results. I dont' know why. 
`attr(df2$datetime, "tzone") <- "GMT"`
`attr(df1$sample_date, "tzone") <- "GMT"`

`ggplot(df2) + geom_line(aes(datetime, Sal1)) + 
  geom_point(aes(sample_date, result_value), data = df1)`

Comment: Ok now realized when changed both to GMT the dates actually changed. Thanks Joran. Is it possible to keep the date time same and only change attribute i.e keep same time and same time zone because when I change only time zone then the data would be messed up.